# Mechanism/purpose of the NAV and its relation to the exposed node problem in 802.11

Tags: mac, 802.11

802.11 uses csma/ca as the mac protocol.

Every station senses the medium, if something is being sent, then they will set their NAV to the duration ID from the packet being sent weather RTS, CTS, DATA, ACK.

RTS/CTS was introduced to mitigate the hidden node and exposed node problems.

The exposed node problem is:

> Consider an example of four nodes labeled R1, S1, S2, and R2, where the two receivers (R1, R2) are out of range of each other, yet the two transmitters (S1, S2) in the middle are in range of each other. Here, if a transmission between S1 and R1 is taking place, node S2 is prevented from transmitting to R2 as it concludes after carrier sense that it will interfere with the transmission by its neighbor S1. However note that R2 could still receive the transmission of S2 without interference because it is out of range of S1.

Taken from wikipedia:[The exposed node problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposed_node_problem)

But if the nodes set their nav to the duration in the RTS packet (which is  then they will be backing off when CTS, therefore the problem will still persist, so is this how the nav works?

Also, in the exposed node problem, why can't the node read from the RTS packet that it is being sent to a different node/AP?

Here another very related unanswered question (almost the same as this one): https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58613/how-do-dcf-and-macaw-solve-the-exposed-node-problem

Edit: here is a diagram (the one on the right) explaining my problem:

[image: this diagram explains the problem, the duration in the rts frame will be set by in nav of the exposed node]

Thank you very much.

Comment: NAV doesn't solve anything, it's just used to save power in receivers that can stop listening to the medium for its duration.

Comment: @Finbarr i did not mean/imply that the nav solves the problem, just how it doesn't contribute to it.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what your actual question is.

Comment: @Finbarr i read that rts/cts exchange helps mitigate exposed node problem, because when the the "exposed node" hears the rts but not the CTS, it knows it can proceed with its transmission
(https://i.imgur.com/iwss8YS.png)
But when the exposed node hears the RTS, it will set its NAV according to the duration in the RTS and will back off for the whole exchange, so either i don't understand how NAV is set, or every source saying that RTS/CTS helps mitigate the exposed node problem is wrong.

Comment: The exposed node either backs off or proceeds with its transmission, it can't do both.

Comment: @Finbarr i know, but which one does it do? back off? (my current understanding due to NAV being set from the RTS it heard) or proceed?

Comment: "because when the the "exposed node" hears the rts but not the CTS, it knows it can proceed with its transmission" - so it proceeds with its transmission

Comment: @Finbarr problem is, what about the nav that is set?
why doesn't the exposed node "back off" when it hears an hears an rts?

Comment: NAV just helps a node that backs off to know how long to back off for. A node that proceeds with transmission isn't backing off,.